# authlogic on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I followed the advice from [this post](http://www.dixis.com/?p=352) in order to get authlogic working in rails 3. However when accessing the application, I get an error in the login template

> undefined method `login' for #<UserSession: no credentials provided>

I grepped around and this message seems to be coming from the `inspect` method of `session/foundation.rb` which ends up in my `UserSession` model. I'm not sure what this means and how it could be solved (I'm pretty new to ruby & rails) . Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255176. Do you just need to restart the server?

Comment: no, mine doesn't run in dev, server restarted several times. the link you have provided is about not running in production env.

Comment: Perhaps you could post copies of your User model UserSession and the schema User.

Answer (score 0):

its easy:

```
acts_as_authentic do |c|
   c.login_field = :login  
 end
```

will fit. in case you have a login-property. else, use e.h. username or email, and adjust it in view.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this tutorial instead: http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic

A few changes to do are:

```
script/generate session user_session to rails generate session user_session
config.gem "authlogic" to gem "authlogic" in Gemfile
```